# ethzasl_icp_mapper service Minimal Example

Tags: ros, icp, ethzasl-icp-mapping, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the ethzasl_icp_mapper service to match some very simple point clouds. However, I get errors like:
ICP failed to converge: no outlier to filter

I create two simple point clouds and try to line them up using the MatchClouds service.
http://pastebin.com/2seS1jUq

Is this example too simple? Am I missing something?

(currently using groovy_released, but have tried other versions with similar results)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204811/ethzasl_icp_mapper-service-minimal-example/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It all depend on your YAML file used when launching the node `ethzasl_icp_mapper`. The default launch files of the repository are made for large point clouds with a lot of redundant information. The default ICP solution (trigger if no YAML file is given) also assume many points.

I suspect that in your case, the chosen configuration is too aggressive on the downsample and on the outlier filter. We've made the registration solution highly configurable to suit a large range of applications. The downside of that is that you need to tune for your needs.

Here some suggestion to start:

- remove all data filters
- remove all outlier filters
- use point-to-point error

For more information on all module available, you can use the `pmicp -l`. I think you should find that in the `bin` folder of the node. This executable can also take two point clouds from disk and a yaml configuration to register point clouds. It might be useful for your tests.

This node rely on `libpointmatcher`, a library independent of ROS. Lately, I'm putting more effort on maintaining that part. The node `ethzasl_icp_mapper` is mainly a showcase for it. Don't hesitate to read our [tutorial page](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/doc/Tutorials.md).

---

Originally posted by [Francois](https://answers.ros.org/users/4341/francois/) with karma: 101 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-03-12**:
Excellent. Thanks Francois. The tutorial page you linked to was very helpful. I had previously only looked at the documentation on [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_configuration) which doesn't specify exactly how to build the yaml file. Also, the point-to-point reference was super-useful.